# install4j + display custom error for install files action

Tags: install4j

In install files action, when the files cannot be created, it displays a message saying it cannot create the file. Is there a way to add custom error message and fail the installation. [image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses "Cancel", the "Install files" action will fail and its configured error message will be displayed. As of install4j 6.0, there is no way to skip this message box if a file installation fails.

As for configuring the error message:

On the "Installer->Screens & actions" step, locate the "Install files" action. The "Error message" property is set to ${i18n:FileCorrupted} by default and the "Failure strategy" property is set to "Quit on failure" by default.

Comment: If the user clicks on yes/no option, will the error message be displayed?

Comment: No, in that case it will retry or ignore.

Comment: I want to display error in case there is any problem like the one displayed in the image. Is there a way for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this.